# Clojure - Create an array of keys if value is true

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am totally new to clojure.

I have a JSON like: `{ "1": true, "2": false, "3": true, "4": false }`

I want to create an array of keys for which the value is true in clojure. In this example the array should be `["1", "3"]`.

Please help me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is pretty broad. What have you tried? I'd look into `filter` as well to filter out entires with a false value.

Comment: I dont understand the question. You mean you only want the keys?

Comment: @jstuartmilne Seems like they want the keys of the pairs with a truthy value.

Comment: Yes, I want an array of keys with a true value.

Comment: welcome to Clojure, I'm assuming you're using data.json or cheshire to marshal the json into a Clojure map. once you've done that then filtering the map by the keys (the first example in leetwinski's answer) will work. This is because maps can be treated like functions which filter takes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

there are also couple of short and simple snippets for that:

```
user> (filter m (keys m))
;;=> ("1" "3")

user> (keep (fn [[k v]] (when v k)) m)
;;=> ("1" "3")

user> (for [[k v] m :when v] k)
;;=> ("1" "3")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're fine with using a vector instead of an array (since you're usually using vectors in Clojure anyway), you can do something like.

```
(defn keys-for-truthy-vals [m]
  (->> m (filter val) (mapv key)))
```

**Note** The `mapv` is only so the map call returns a vector. If you want a `seq`, just use `map`.

Comment: `key` and `val` already exist to return the key and value of a map pair, so the `let` bindings are unnecessary.

Comment: @Lee thanks! I forgot about that. Updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The same as already provided, just staying in maps.

(keys (filter val m))

Answer (score 0):

If your map is `a` Something like `(->> (filter (fn [[k v]] v) a) (map (fn [[k v]] k)))` will work. You can't do it with just a map because you need to drop certain values, so there will need to be some reducing or filtering.

Comment: I tried (->> (filter (fn [[k v]] v) flavor-ids) (map (fn [[k v]] k))) But I am getting an error "Uncaught Error: Oops, Missing expected object key 'data'".

Comment: Style nitpicking: if you use threading macros like `->>`, then pull the "first" argument also into the first place.  E.g. `(->> a (filter (,,,)) (map (,,,)))`

Answer (score 0):

There is built-in function [in the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo) for this:

```
(submap-by-vals map-arg keep-vals & opts)

Returns a new map containing entries with the specified vals. Throws for missing vals,
unless `:missing-ok` is specified. Usage:

(submap-by-vals {:a 1 :b 2 :A 1} #{1  }             )  =>  {:a 1 :A 1}
(submap-by-vals {:a 1 :b 2 :A 1} #{1 9} :missing-ok )  =>  {:a 1 :A 1}
```

You could then just use the `keys` function on the resulting map.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

`(->> foo (filter second) keys)`

where foo is a map.